# Using php, how do I query from certain keywords stored in rows in my MySQL table to display relevant information?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named news with a row $keyword that contains keywords for my blog article.

Suppose $keyword contains tech,technology,entertainment each different for each article.

How do I query $keyword using php so that when the page loads only the articles containing the keywords 'tech' is displayed.

Can I use the LIMIT or should I use the SELECT function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SELECT * from your table where keyword ="tech" LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: It says this "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table where keyword ='tech' LIMIT 0, 10' at line 1"

Comment: whats your column name where keywords are stored?

Comment: And now I get this "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lowervalue, highervalue' at line 1"

Comment: Column name is $keyword

Comment: how come column name is $keyword ??

Comment: Sorry CodingAnt,I'm really confused as I'm a newbie in php. I guess the column name is "news" and the row name is $keyword.

Comment: so may be you can use SELECT * from your table where news ="tech" LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: please run this  "DESC your_table_name"; and post the result

Comment: The code worked. Php is querying my table properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 'like' evaluator allows you to match value fields with partial strings. In this instance `%` acts as a wild card, so `%tech%` matches all queries containing 'tech':

`mysql_query("select * from news where keyword like '%tech%' limit lowervalue, highervalue");`

example

`mysql_query("select * from news where keyword like '%tech%' limit 5");`

Comment: I get this error message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table where keyword ='tech' LIMIT 0, 10' at line 1"

Comment: @Susan ,look at the answer that I posted..use `like` keyword

Comment: Codelover, you're code works! Only if I remove the limit function. Whenever I'm including the limit function they're showing me syntax error.

Comment: Now its working codelover. Can you please clarify why I'm using the limit 5 function here? Thank you again.

Comment: @susan ,it is mainly used to restrict the values which is retrieved from table..Any way cheers that it worked for you..Also mark the answer as correct so that it may be useful for others also